# regular expression in VS 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

How should I write the regular expression in VS2010's search function?

I need to find randomly words that begins with " and ends with ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `"[^"]+"`? That matches a quote, followed by one or more non-quote characters, followed by another quote.

If you only want to allow ASCII alphanumeric characters (`A-Z, a-z, 0-9`), use `":a+"`.

By the way, here are [the docs for VS 2010 regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: In the class with 10 000 code and there are mountains of words that begins with " and end with ". For instance "asdf", "fgdg", "a34", "3tvcc". I need to find all words that begins and ends with '"'

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPattern = "^\"(.*)?\""; //perform non greedy match until it finds first "

    foreach (string s in numbers)
    {

        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");
        }
    }
```